# how to read custom property files with command line argument in a spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, configuration-files

when startup my spring boot application, I want to set a custom config file path by using command line argument, for example:

```
java -jar some.jar -DConfigPath=conf/config.local(or conf/config.prod)
```

So how to read this file to generate a spring configuration?
Can I use the Annotation `@PropertySource` in some "dynamic" way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I find the annotation @PropertySource can get the value injected by command line argument

```
   @Configuration
   @ConfigurationProperties
   @PropertySource(value = "file:${ConfigPath}")
   public class MyConfig {
            @Getter
            @Value("${property_name}")
            private String myproperty;
    }
```

Comment: HI, when I run the command it gives me error `Could not resolve placeholder 'ConfigPath' in value "file:${ConfigPath}" ` is there something else to do?

Comment: Also what is property_name?

Answer (score 1):

Try using

> spring.config.location

Something like this

```
java -jar some.jar --spring.config.location=file:some-project/src/main/resources/conf/config.prod
```

this should read your config just like any application.properties file

Comment: well, changing the argument name seems much trouble since it is a issue left over by history, so...I may try to solve it in my own codes

Comment: @LENS What do you mean by left over by history? The given answer should just work fine and that's what you asked - 'I want to set a custom config file path by using command line argument'