# Spring Boot read properties file from command line Could not resolve placeholder 'ConfigPath'

Tags: java, spring-boot, jar, configuration-files

I'm trying to read a configuration file from command line. In main I do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        if(args.length > 0) {
            SpringApplication.run(HeliosAdminBackendApplication.class, args);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error");
            System.exit(0); 
        }       
    }
```

And, [following this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50245650/how-to-read-custom-property-files-with-command-line-argument-in-a-spring-boot-ap), I've created a class `MyConfig` like this:

```
import lombok.Getter;

@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties
@PropertySource(value = "file:${ConfigPath}")
public class MyConfig {

     @Getter
     @Value("${property_name}")
     private String myproperty;

}
```

Then I've created the .jar file, then went in the folder containing the jar and try to run it by doing:

```
java -jar myapp.jar --spring.config.location=file:application.yml
```

My application.yml file is the same folder of my jar. I've also set the path to `C:/my/path/to/folder/` but the error persists. Is the path written wrong? Or do I have to add/modify something in the code?

**EDIT**

Full stack trace:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
>   Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed
>   to parse configuration class
>   [it.sysdata.helios_backend_admin.HeliosAdminBackendApplication];
>   nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not
>   resolve placeholder 'ConfigPath' in value "file:${ConfigPath}"
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:181)
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:315)
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:232)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:691)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:528)
>           at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
>           at it.sysdata.helios_backend_admin.HeliosAdminBackendApplication.main(HeliosAdminBackendApplication.java:24)
>           ... 8 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'ConfigPath' in value
>   "file:${ConfigPath}"
>           at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:172)
>           at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:124)
>           at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:237)
>           at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:211)
>           at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractEnvironment.java:575)
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processPropertySource(ConfigurationClassParser.java:450)
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:271)
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:242)
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:191)
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:295)
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:242)
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:199)
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:167)
>           ... 21 more

Comment: Keep the file inside resource folder and build jar

Comment: No I need the file to be external and pass the path when running jar...

Comment: Try java -jar {jar-file-name}.jar 
--spring.config.location=file:///C:/{file-path}/{file-name}.yml   OR java -jar app.jar --spring.config.location=xxx.yml

Comment: Hi, not working... I've updated the question with the full stacktrace

Comment: that is not the full stacktrace... read at the bottom, it says "21 more"

Comment: I think you should use "--spring.config.additional-location" for reading external configuration

Comment: @RahulWagh that's it. Thank you so much. Why do I have to use "additional" and not just location? I do not have any other .yml file in my project

Comment: You welcome, i have posted a detailed answer below. Because this comment section is too small to explain and if you like the answer and able to solve your problem then please accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer for your question regarding Why do I have to use "additional" and not just location?

First of all when ever you use spring.config.location for loading configuration properties then spring-boot trys to search the configuration at classpath or under config directory. Here is the order of search -

```
            file:./config/
            file:./
            classpath:/config/
            classpath:/
```

But remember if you are using the spring.config.locaton then it will always look for either "classpath" or "config" not the external configuration.

To load the external configuration/custom configuration then spring boot provides "spring.config.additional-location" which search the configuration in following order -

```
            file:./custom-config/
            classpath:custom-config/ (This is was your case)
            file:./config/
            file:./
            classpath:/config/
            classpath:/
```

I hope now got the answer why to use the "spring.config.additional-location" for loading external configuration.

Comment: don't think this answer this is fully correct: ```java -jar myapp.jar --spring.config.location=file:./application.yml``` should work note the **./** when using ```spring.config.additional-location``` the external properties are appended with the internal properties